# Randomly arrange a list<object>

Tags: c#, list, shuffle

I have a list of objects that I want to randomly arrange or jumble up. Is this possible?
The list is built up from company products. I take the top 2 of each company and the add the rest to another list. I want to jumble the second list.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807128/an-extension-method-on-ienumerable-needed-for-shuffling

Comment: Some good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp)

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle

Comment: Have you had a look into any of these?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+shuffle

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks, did not know the name for it. Explained the same process in an interview once, and the interviewer seemed to think my approach was 'interesting'. They also declined me as I was not 'strong' as another candidate. I did not even lift a weight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var shuffledList = list.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

This works fine, because OrderBy implementation first creates a list of keys and then sorts using the generated keys. So the lamba expression is only called once for each item. During the sort processes, each item in the list has it's own, random sort key.

Comment: That can make problems for the OrderBy method when comparing same objects can produce different results.

Comment: @Tomas: No, you're wrong. Take a look at OrderBy implementation: class System.Linq.EnumerableSorter<TElement>, method Sort. I've added a sentence about that to my answer.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/01/31/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-four/ explains why this can crash

Answer (score 1):

You don't need O(N*LogN) operation. Just use [FisherYatesShuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593077/932418)

See Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 1):

Try [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) - it builds lists of objects, and provides inclemently generated values for properties (you also can provide any value manually):

```
var products = Builder<Product>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build();
```

If you want (non-incremental) random items, you can pick them from any collection:

```
var randomProducts = Pick<Product>.UniqueRandomList(3).From(products);
```