# How to prevent duplicate random numbers

Tags: c#

I write a simple code and I would like to prevent duplicate random numbers.

What is the simplest way to do it?

```
 Random rnd = new Random();

        int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;

        n1 = rnd.Next(1, 37);
        n2 = rnd.Next(1, 37);
        n3 = rnd.Next(1, 37);
        n4 = rnd.Next(1, 37);
        n5 = rnd.Next(1, 37);
        n6 = rnd.Next(1, 37);
        n7 = rnd.Next(1, 7);

        Console.WriteLine("1 Number ({0})", n1);
        Console.WriteLine("2 Number ({0})", n2);
        Console.WriteLine("3 Number ({0})", n3);
        Console.WriteLine("4 Number ({0})", n4);
        Console.WriteLine("5 Number ({0})", n5);
        Console.WriteLine("6 Number ({0})", n6);
        Console.WriteLine("Additionl Number ({0})", n7);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you setting its max and min limit?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/21ce91f4-9763-4f97-b558-16120c0583d3

Comment: Hi Nikhil, what do you mean?

Comment: You want to simulate a lotto draw or shuffling a deck of cards, but what you're actually simulating is rolling dice.

Comment: And that `additional number` is independent of the others, right?

Comment: @DARK-SPIRIT: this is what I mean. `rnd.Next(1, 37);`. Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: [Unique number in random?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592166/unique-number-in-random)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Use this instead:

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    lock (syncLock)
    { // synchronize
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
int randomNumber = RandomNumber(0, 10); // random number between 0 and 10
```

Comment: You're assuming a multithreaded application, but even with one thread you can get duplicate numbers.