# How to choose different random number each time in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, random

If I have an array that contains some values. How to get different random number each time - which represents an indexes - in which to get different values from the array ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the selected result from the list of available locations and then randomising from the remaining locations?

Comment: Don't "generate" random numbers. Collect all possible numbers and shuffle them. Then enumerate the shuffled numbers. -- `foreach(int randomIndex in Enumerable.Range(0,5).OrderBy(rnd.Next())) { [...] }` might be a start.

Comment: @phuzi : I cant because I need this array in different methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the sequence of the range you need, and sort it randomly. Then, put the values in a stack and pick from that stack. For example:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var randomValues = new Stack<int>(Enumerable.Range(0,5).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
var randomIndex1 = randomValues.Pop();
var randomIndex2 = randomValues.Pop();
```

Comment: Why did you re-open this question (which had previously been closed as a duplicate), just to post an answer that proposes [a sub-optimal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)? This looks a bit like abuse of your gold tag badge privileges to me. Can you explain why you disagree that this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592166/unique-number-in-random) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931528/random-number-generator-with-no-duplicates)?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, you are correct, I think I was a little to quick to re-open the question. I though the top answer in the duplicate question just shuffled the array, but it does fill it also. So yes, the only difference with my answer is really only that I also show an easy way to pick the values using a stack.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for replying. I just got a couple of flags about suspicious behavior here, and wanted to give you a heads up. In the future, it would probably work out better to specifically mention what your answer was adding that is *not* covered by the answers in a proposed duplicate (just like we ask the asker to clarify in their question when they are protesting a duplicate closure).